# Combining Grep Checks in Bash Script Condition

Tags: bash, grep

I do have egrep (i.e. grep -E) available, and I am sure it is possible, but I spent entirely too much time trying to figure out how to one-line this.  awk is also an acceptable alternative to grep.

Anybody care to turn this into a single "until" statement?  Both grep queries need to exist in xrandr output, not just one or the other.

```
while true ; do
    if xrandr | grep -q "primary 720x720+0+0" ; then
        if xrandr | grep -q "connected 512x512+720+0" ; then
            return
        fi
    fi
    ...
done
```

Comment: How about showing us what the raw `xrandr` output is and what the expected output is? Could be interesting, no?

Comment: Or, heck, `xrandr_out=$(xrandr); [[ $xrandr_out = *"primary 720x720+0+0"* ]] && [[ $xrandr_out = *"connected 512x12+720+0"* ]]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

grep is the wrong tool for this job. You *could* use awk:

```
if xrandr | awk '
    /primary 720x720[+]0[+]0/ { found_a=1 }
    /connected 512x512[+]720[+]0/ { found_b=1 }
    END { if (found_a && found_b) { exit(0) } else { exit(1) } }
'; then
  echo "Yes, found both strings"
else
  echo "No, did not find both strings"
fi
```

...or you could just do your logic right in the shell:

```
xrandr_out=$(xrandr)
if [[ $xrandr_out = *"primary 720x720+0+0"* ]] \
&& [[ $xrandr_out = *"connected 512x512+720+0"* ]]; then
  echo "Yes, found both strings"
else
  echo "No, did not find both strings"
fi
```

Either way, the simple thing to do is to embed the logic in a function:

```
xrandr_all_good() {
  xrandr | awk '
    /primary 720x720[+]0[+]0/ { found_a=1 }
    /connected 512x512[+]720[+]0/ { found_b=1 }
    END { if (found_a && found_b) { exit(0) } else { exit(1) } }
  '
}

until xrandr_all_good; do
  : "...stuff here..."
done
```